# global import stylus once in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, stylus, vue-loader, stylus-loader

My stylus global file is imported multiple times.
How import global stylus in vue?

my `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      stylus: {
        import: [
          '~@/assets/stylus/reset.styl',
          '~@/assets/stylus/vars.styl',
          '~@/assets/stylus/mixins.styl',
          '~@/assets/stylus/atomic.styl',
          '~@/assets/stylus/grid.styl',
          '~@/assets/stylus/colors.styl',
          '~@/assets/stylus/global.styl'
        ]
      }
    }
  },
}
```

my result
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esSU9.png)

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks like some reset styles. Are you importing your reset file into any of those other files?

Comment: Also can you please add which loaders you're using to the question?